# Is Pcanvas support double click actions to zoom instead of drag actions?

Tags: java, piccolo

When I played the zoom example of Piccolo demo, I got one wonder that is Pcanvas only support drag actions to zoom ?

Thus I went to review the source code of Pcanvas, then I found it has one variable `PZoomEventHandler` to control the zoom actions. Furthermore, I reviewed the source code of `PZoomEventHandler`, I realized it inheritances from `PDragSequenceEventHandler`. Is this mean Pcanvas only support drag actions to zoom ?

If I'm correct, following are my details queries:

1. If I want to achieve double click actions to zoom, which class in
   Piccolo I should use to let PZoomEventHandler inherit from instead
   of `PDragSequenceEventHandler` ?
2. If I change the `PZoomEventHandler`, definitely it will affect all
   zoom performance. Is it better I add one more variable like
   `PZoomEventHandlerV2` in Pcanvas to handle special zoom by using
   double click actions ?

Thank you for your time and suggestion. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PDragSequenceEventHandler` simplifies implementation of handlers that are based on mouse dragging events. In your case you can derive from `PBasicInputEventHandler`. Also, you can add as many event listeners as you need, just make sure they don't interfere with each other. Read more about event listeners in [Adding User Interaction](http://piccolo2d.googlecode.com/svn/site/learn/patterns.html#Adding_User_Interaction).

Below is an example of a zoom handler that reacts to a mouse wheel rotation (not sure how you wanted to un-zoom in double click based zooming so I used a mouse wheel). The example keeps the original zoom handler which is based on dragging and adds a new one based on the mouse wheel. You can also remove the original zoom handler if needed using `removeInputEventListener` method.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.PCanvas;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.PLayer;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.event.PBasicInputEventHandler;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.event.PInputEvent;
import edu.umd.cs.piccolo.nodes.PPath;

public class TestZoom {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {   
            public void run() {   
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestZoom");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                final PCanvas canvas = new PCanvas() {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(300, 300);
                    }
                };

                PLayer layer = new PLayer();
                canvas.getCamera().addLayer(0, layer);
                canvas.getCamera().getRoot().addChild(layer);

                final PPath node = PPath.createRectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
                canvas.getLayer().addChild(node);

                canvas.addInputEventListener(new MouseZoomHandler());

                frame.add(canvas);            
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MouseZoomHandler extends PBasicInputEventHandler {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelRotated(final PInputEvent event) {
            final double scale = 1 - 0.2 * event.getWheelRotation(); 
            final Point2D point = event.getPosition();
            event.getCamera().scaleViewAboutPoint(scale, 
                    point.getX(), point.getY());                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very clear explanation, thanks for the sharing, Aqua!